# USB Linux bootable for Chromebook

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, usb, chromebook

So say I want to create a USB bootable for Linux to run on my Chromebook.

1. I am aware that there are many ways to do this for example Pendrive, Rufus, or chrosh.
2. I then have to enable my Chromebook to be USB booting by typing `sudo crossystem dev_boot_usb=1 dev_boot_legacy=1` in developer mode in chrosh.
3. Now when I restart my Chromebook and it shows that OS verification is off, I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to boot from my USB.

Can someone confirm that steps 1 through 3 are correct, thanks?

Now my question is, when I boot Linux form a USB, will the data on the OS be saved on the USB or the chromebook system drive? By data i mean all the applications and files that I have on the linux OS. If so, how would i change it to make the data save on the USB and how much storage would i need on the USB. As you all might know, Chromebooks have a very small memory space.

Comment: Step 1 is correct, no idea about step 3 because I don't have a chromebook.

Comment: what data do you mean? Your personal files?

Comment: Do you _need_ to keep ChromeOS? Or would you be fine with removing everything Chrome from your entire system?

Comment: BY data i mean all the applications and downloads i do on linux